# Add an extra field to the navigation menu box?

Tags: menus, navigation, options

Goal:
I like to use a subtitle in the navigation bar.

The most logic location, in my opinion, would be Appearance > Menu and add a field below navigation label called subtitle. So the end user can easily add and change a subtitle there for the different menu items.

Looking at `wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php`, I can't find an action to hook onto, is this correct? Does anyone have an idea to accomplish this?

Comment: have you ticked the 'Description' box under 'Show advanced menu properties' in the 'screen options' tab in the ***appearance -> menus*** page? this might be related: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Comment: That is BRILLIANT... can you post this as an answer so I can accept it and mark it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you ticked the 'Description' box under 'Show advanced menu properties' in the 'screen options' tab in the ***appearance -> menus*** page?

and have a look at this related post: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output